# Spring boot gradle kotlin build

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, java-8, kotlin

I am trying to create JAVA springboot project with gradle build.I wanted to try out new kotlin support for springboot. Wondering how i can add bootrun task inside build.gradle.kts file.

```
plugins {

}

val coreServiceVersion = "3.0.0"

dependencies {

}
```

That's the over all structure of build.gradle.kts

Comment: Why wont you just create a spring boot project in intellij with gradle as a build tool? or something similar in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following configuration:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    val kotlinVersion = "1.2.41"
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.0.2.RELEASE"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version kotlinVersion
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring") version kotlinVersion
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.4.RELEASE"
}

val coreServiceVersion = "3.0.0"

version = "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}
```

See https://github.com/sdeleuze/spring-boot-kotlin-demo/ for a complete project.